# Home Page working properly in localhost but throwing error after hosting on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, hosting, vercel

I created a todo app using `react`, `react-router-dom`, `redux`, and `localStorage`. It is working fine in localhost, but after hosting in vercel it is showing my error page. When I go to `"hostURL/addtodo"` it is showing the intended page.

I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <HomePage /> },
      { path: '/addtodo', element: <AddPage /> },
      { path: '/edit/:id', element: <EditPage /> },
    ],
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
])

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}
```

```
function RootLayout() {
  return <Outlet />
}
```

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(() => {
  const localValue = localStorage.getItem('MYTODOS')
  if (typeof localValue === 'undefined') return []
  //console.log(localValue)
  return JSON.parse(localValue)
})

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('MYTODOS', JSON.stringify(todos))
}, [todos])
```

GitHub Link: [Repo](https://github.com/sumanmaji4/AulaCubeAssignment)

After Hosting: [Hosted](https://aula-cube-assignment-chi.vercel.app/)

Comment: We need some more debugging details. You say that navigating to `"hostURL/addtodo"` works without issue, but what URL path are you on when the error page is rendered? What is the relevance of the last code snippet with the state and effect? Please [edit] to clarify the issue, and to provide a complete [mcve] and your exact reproduction steps to produce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong in the routing.

## Issue

You have used `typeof localValue === 'undefined'` to check if the local storage value is undefined. This condition will never be true because typeof will return a string, and it will never be equal to the string 'undefined'.

## Solution

It uses `localValue ? JSON.parse(localValue) : []` to check if the local storage value is truthy and then parse it, otherwise, it sets an empty array.

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(() => {
  const localValue = localStorage.getItem('MYTODOS');
  return localValue ? JSON.parse(localValue) : [];
});

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('MYTODOS', JSON.stringify(todos));
}, [todos]);
```

I have pulled your repo and it shows the same hosted website error on local too. I had some spare time. I have fixed 7 bugs on your repo.
PR [link](https://github.com/sumanmaji4/AulaCubeAssignment/pull/1)

Please do check, now `Todo` is working fine.

Comment: @drew-reese Thanks for the edit! I'm a new contributor, have to learn much from contributors like you!

Comment: Thanks. Also FWIW you could simplify the lazy loader to just `return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MYTODOS")) ?? []`.

Comment: @SumanMaji I'm glad I could help! If you want to fine-tune your React concepts, check out react.dev. It's a fantastic resource.